# How to compare two files in shell script?

Tags: unix, shell, filecompare

Here is my scenario.
I have two files which are having records with each record's 3-25 characters is an identifier. Based on this I need to compare both of them and update the old file with the new file data if their identifiers match. Identifiers start with 01.
Please look at the script below.
This is giving some error as "argument expected at line 12 which I am not able to understand.

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read line
  do
    c=`echo $line|grep '^01' `
    if [ $c -ne NULL ];
      then
        var=`echo $line|cut -c 3-25`
    fi
    while read i
      do
        d=`echo $i|grep '^01' `
        if [ $d -ne NULL ];
          then
            var1=`echo $i|cut -c 3-25`
            if [ $var -eq $var1 ];
              then
                $line=$i
            fi
        fi
      done < test_monday
  done < test_sunday
```

Please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: @ALN,could you please also post some sample data so that would be more easy to understand the requirement.thanks

Comment: If you post some sample data u could get not only a shell script solution but also some more simple solutions than a shell script either by awk,sed,perl etc.

Comment: the first file is like this
011111111111111111111+<some data>
012554565645645455555+<some data>
....
...
...
the second file is 
011111111111111111111111+<changed data>
015456565653565644444444+<some data>
....
...
so ihae to compare both files from 1-25 characters(upto + sybol) as key and if second file has matched record ..i have to replace it in first file...or else just append it to first file.........

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is :

```
if [ "$d" != NULL ];
```

Try.

Comment: that helped in removing first error...thanks....but there is one more simialr error when comparing both the indicators....in
if [ $var == $var1 ]; 
help needed........

Comment: DId you make sure the "Spacings" in if statement?

Comment: The thing about comparing string in bash is that you should put quot around it unless you are so sure that it will never have space in it. Because Bash will substitute the value of that variable in as parameter for "if" and parameters are separated by space (therefore if the value contain space, you get multiple variable). So first, wrapping it with quotes. Next is that, use "==" and "!=" when you compare strings. :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [DIFF](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm) command

```
diff file1 file2 > whats_the_diff.txt
```

Comment: Thats not what I needed. I need to compare only the identifiers and update like in database.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are writing a script for portability to the original Bourne shell or others that do not support the feature, in Bash and ksh [you should use the `[[` form of test](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for strings and files.

There is a reduced need for quoting and escaping, additional conditions such as pattern and regular expression matching and the ability to use `&&` and `||` instead of `-a` and `-o`.

```
if [[ $var == $var1 ]]
```

Also, "NULL" is not a special value in Bash and ksh and so your test will always succeed since `$d` is  tested against the literal string "NULL".

```
if [[ $d != "" ]]
```

or

```
if [[ $d ]]
```

For numeric values (not including leading zeros unless you're using octal), you can use numeric expressions. You can omit the dollar sign for variables in this context.

```
numval=41
if ((++numval >= 42))  # increment then test
then
    echo "don't panic"
fi
```

It's not necessary to use `echo` and `cut` for substrings. In Bash and ksh you can do:

```
var=${line:3:23}
```

Note: `cut` uses character positions for the beginning and end of a range, while this shell construct uses starting position and character count so you have to adjust the numbers accordingly.

And it's a good idea to [get away from using backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). Use `$()` instead. This can be nested and quoting and escaping is reduced or easier.